# Why does my JSON-Simple JSONArray give me a nullpointer exception?

Tags: java, json, nullpointerexception, arrays, json-simple

I'm following this tutuorial [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/), and my JSON object is near enough the same, except I have this sort of format:

```
{"user":{
    "SomeKeys":"SomeValues",
    "SomeList":["val1","val2"]
    }
}
```

Here is my relevant code:

```
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("exampleJson.json"));

JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
JSONObject user = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("user");
JSONArray list = (JSONArray) user.get("SomeList");
```

Then my program goes off an gets the values form the keys etc. Or it would but I get a `NullPointerException` from eclipse. *Why is this?*

It should unpackage my `.json` file into `jsonObject`, unpackage the "user" key as a JSONObject `user`, then unpackage the "SomeList" key as a JSONArray called `list`. Except when it does so it must be trying to put one of `val1` or `val2` into a part of the JSONArray that does not exist and just points into the abyss of `null`. *What have I done <strike>to deserve this</strike> wrong ?*

**How do I fix my program?**

Comment: Isn't "SomeList":["val1","val2"] just an array instead of a JSONArray

Comment: I tried your code and it works perfectly for me... Let me know if you want to post the full code of what I tried.

Comment: Have you tried looking with a debugger?

Comment: @Joel No, but I will do at work tomorrow.

Comment: @aymeric That would be helpful, maybe then I can spot where our code has diverged.

Comment: @D3mon-1stVFW not in the purview of JSON-Simple, though I'm happy to be corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working well for me

```
public class App {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException {
        final Object obj = new JSONParser().parse(new FileReader("D:/a.json"));
        final JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        final JSONObject user = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("user");
        final JSONArray list = (JSONArray) user.get("SomeList");
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

File `D:/exampleJson.json`

```
{"user":{
    "SomeKeys":"SomeValues",
    "SomeList":["val1","val2"]
    }
}
```

output is

```
["val1","val2"]
```

Comment: Why have you made those objects final?

Answer (score 1):

Using the exact same json file:

```
{"user":{
    "SomeKeys":"SomeValues",
    "SomeList":["val1","val2"]
    }
}
```

Here is the code I use (with the imports to really make sure we have the same ones):

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Object obj = new JSONParser().parse(new FileReader("t.json"));

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        JSONObject user = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("user");
        JSONArray list = (JSONArray) user.get("SomeList");
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
["val1","val2"]
```

I used maven and m2e to import the library. The version used for this test was `json-simple-1.1.jar`.